# Clearly show count and amount in the same table cell

Tags: tables

What would be a clear presentation of something that the user counts and values at the same cell?

for example, on a users table I want to show how many accounts and its total worth:

```
| User  | Account totals  |  
|-------|-----------------|  
| Alice | 15,  $ 500      |
| Bob   | 107, $ 305,130  |
```

I can use (text) alignments and font styles.

Comment: why not separate cells?

Comment: @jon a waste of real estate and focus: headers, grid lines X 3 columns that show this data group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to achieve here is a **visual grouping** of the two values, account count and total worth, aiding the visual distinction between the two.

This can be done by **highlighting the most important of the two**, e.g.:

1. **15**, $500
2. 15 ($500) with "($500)" in a dimmed color

Highlighting, by nature, requires you to be able to identify one value as more important than the other.

Alternatively, you can **create the grouping via layout**. This can be done - as suggested in your example - by mimicking two columns in the table.

Comment: I've resolved the whitespace layout by replacing the order of the values: "$ 550 (15)". after reading your answer, I understand that I do consider the amount to be more important. Thanks!

Comment: @Asaf that was going to be my suggestion - $550 (15)